# Eclipse Neon with PyDev: Where to set a breakpoint

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-neon

I work with **Eclipse NEON
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)**
I did a lot of debugging in Eclipse with java. With Python and PyDev I'm new in this configuration.

Problem
I don't see any way how to set a breakpoint, thus I can't debug.

```
CTRL-SHIFT B:  <no reaction>
<symbol menu>: <No breakpoint symbol>
<context menu: <No toogle breakpoint or anything the like>
Reset perspective PyDev: <nothing>
```

Ironie: The button SKIP ALL BREAKPOINTS can be toggle on/off. Still there is no use of this, as long I can't get a breakpoint.

Any ideas? What's wrong?

Comment: Double-click on the line number - breakpoint is set.

Comment: Double-Clicking does set a bookmark. No Breakpoint is set. I use preconfigured Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600. and add PyDev 5.5.0.2017001191708. Is this configuration a problem source?

Comment: Could be a project set up issue. I would try to re-create the project as a first step.

Comment: Re-creation of the project didn't improve, So I tried to install another eclispe build. Using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) Build id: 20161208-0600, then added PyDev. Now I can set breakpoint by Double-clicking on the line number. Thanks  postoronnim.